# influx Error: flag provided but not defined

Tags: command-line-interface, influxdb, influxdb-2

Trying to make my `influx` working and according to [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/shell/#execute-an-influxql-command-and-quit-with-execute), I should be able to do `influx -execute` but this is what I'm getting:

```sh
$ influx -execute 'SHOW DATABASES'
Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -execute

NAME:
   influx - Influx Client

USAGE:
   influx [command]

COMMANDS:
   version              Print the influx CLI version
   ping                 Check the InfluxDB /health endpoint
. . .


$ influx ping
OK

$ influx version
Influx CLI 2.2.1 (git: 31ac783) build_date: 2021-11-09T21:24:22Z
```

Maybe I'm using influx 1.x syntax while under 2.x?

I looked around in
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/get-started/
but didn't seem to have found how to do it in 2.x

Answer (score 2):

To connect to InfluxDB 1.x, you need to use `influx` binary bundled with the distribution.

InfluxDB 2.x stores data in `buckets`. To list them you can use `influx bucket list`. See [influx CLI](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/reference/cli/influx/) for more.